# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable Cast error

Tags: c#, linq, list, collections

I have the following model classes. I want to retrieve object of `AddressMatch` from `AddressMatches` list based on some condition.

```
public class AddressMatchList
{
    public List<AddressMatch> AddressMatches { get; set; }
}

public class AddressMatch
{
    public string HouseRange { get; set; }
    public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public string AddressIdentifier { get; set; } 
}
```

I tried this:

```
AddressMatch selectedMatchedAddress = new AddressMatch();   
selectedMatchedAddress = addressMatches.AddressMatches.Where(a => a.AddressIdentifier == "cpr");
```

But got error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to
>   'AddressMatch'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a
>   cast?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Where` returns an enumerable (list of) items, where you expect just one.

You could use this if you want to make sure there is just one matching (`SingleOrDefault` will give an exception if more than one matching item is found):

```
selectedMatchedAddress = addressMatches.AddressMatches
                         .SingleOrDefault(a => a.AddressIdentifier == "cpr");
```

Or this if you just want the first matching item:

```
selectedMatchedAddress = addressMatches.AddressMatches
                         .FirstOrDefault(a => a.AddressIdentifier == "cpr");
```

In both cases it is important to check `selectedMatchedAddress` for `null`.

Comment: Great Explanation!

Answer (score 3):

That's because in the LINQ expression

```
.Where(a => a.AddressIdentifier == "cpr")
```

There is no way of know if the result of it will be one item o several items, the result of that will be a `Enumerable<T>`.

You can use `FirstOfDefault()` to make sure the expressions only returns a item of AddressMatch`.

```
.Where(a => a.AddressIdentifier == "cpr").FirstOfDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<AddressMatch> a1 = addressMatches.AddressMatches
                        .Where(a => a.AddressIdentifier == "cpr")
                        .ToList<AddressMatch>();
```

`Where` returns an `IEnumerable` of items, which is not compatible with `List<AddressMatch>`. The `ToList<AddressMatch>()` method at the end creates a compatible list from the IEnumerable created by `Where`.

Comment: As mentioned above, the Where returns an enumerable (list of) items, so the cast was failing.. So I have just changed to make it list instead of a single item.

Comment: I can see that, but OP may not understand, so it is customary to give some explanation with the code about your changes.